# Can a user create a Table in SQL Database through a Form?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a new project that will let users create new party event through a simple form and I need that data stored as a new table for each new event.  What I wanted to know is if its possible for user to create new table in my Database by submitting the form?  I know that you can write data to columns, but I have no idea if you can actually write an actual table with columns.

I'm working with MVC 4 and this is sort of new to me and I'm not sure if such thing is possible so wanted to check to make sure before I move to alternate path.

Thanks

Comment: this is definitely possible. It's a sql create db call to the database. Doesn't matter if it comes from Form or SSMS. But be warned, this is something well out of best practices. Something as dramatic as creating or dropping DB's shouldn't be done from web app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I wanted to know is if its possible for user to create new table
>   in my Database by submitting the form?

Of course that it is possible. If you couldn't insert records in a database after suibmitting a form in ASP.NET MVC, then this framework would be useless garbage.

> I know that you can write data to columns, but I have no idea if you
>   can actually write an actual table with columns.

You may take a look at plain [`ADO.NET`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e80y5yhx.aspx) or an ORM such as [`Entity Framework`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/ef) which both allow you to query a relational database. By the way you might consider reading some of the getting started tutorials on the http://asp.net/mvc site. Here's [`one example`](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) you might go through.

Comment: exactly. Not a question of can, more a question of is this a good idea.

Comment: Thanks, that example you linked is pretty close to what I need to do.  I just need to go through it and familiarize myself with it.

Answer (score 3):

*First off:* **STOP USING THAT DESIGN**

Read this page before you go any further too: [Database Normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

the schema for your database should looks something like this:

```
users
id,name,etc...

parties
id,user_id,date,etc...
```

Using your way you will run into MASSIVE problems down the road

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can write SQL DDL Sentences. "[CREATE TABLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language#CREATE_TABLE_statement)" is the concrete expresion you need to use in this case. It may takes different syntax according the database you are using